# Using variables in batch query

Tags: batch-file

I am stumped as to why this does not work. I wish to find a key then delete it. I have commented out the delete for testing as it produces an error as seen by the "reg query" line.

```
@echo off

for /f  %%a in (' 
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" ^|
    find "StartRCM"
') do (
     set "regs=%%a"
)

echo %regs%

set key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\%regs%"
echo %key%

REM reg delete %key% /f
reg query %key%
```

The output is:

```
C:\>test2.bat
StartRCM
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\StartRCM"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\>
```

**Edit1**

```
C:\>Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
    StartRCM    REG_DWORD    0x0
...

C:\>
```

Comment: It would certainly help us were you to provide the actual output from the following command, `Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"`, and explain what it is you're trying to retrieve and execute. Additionally, you may find the output of `For /?` useful, _especially with refererence to tokens and delimiters_.

Comment: Simply find a key, put it in a variable and then delete the key.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for putting any output into a variable at all. Please read the output of `Reg Delete /?` and if you really feel it necessary, _(should you wish to delete a **value** as opposed to a **key**)_, `Reg Query /?` and `For /?`.

Comment: Thanks Compo, yes it is a value I wish to delete. Correct. The purpose of the variable is the name of the desired "value" changes however it always has a constant string component so using this method I can find the value and delete it as reg delete does not allow wildcards. The code above is a simplified example.

Comment: Well, you're specifically using a constant string, `StartRCM`, so what's the point in that? Please return to your question and edit it, _trying much better to explain the task and issue_.

Comment: Yes correct. If the value we need to delete was "StartRCM-abc-def-ghi" Then this code would find it as it would match "StartRCM".

Comment: Please show me a list of the possible values, registry values are almost always constant, _(why would a provider create randomly different registry entries, they also need to look them up, hence the reason they're stored in a register)_. I cannot see a question or issue without proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f  %%a in ('
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" ^|
    find "StartRCM"
') do (
     set "regs=%%a"
)

echo "%regs%"

set "key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"
echo %key%

if defined regs reg delete "%key%" /v "%regs%" /f
reg query "%key%"
```

Your initial code with adjustment for the *value* of `StartRCM`.

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
>      StartRCM    REG_DWORD    0x0
> ```

From your query output:

- The 1st line is the *key*.
- `StartRCM` is the *value*.
- `REG_DWORD` is the *data type*.
- `0x0` is the *data*.